# Summarise arbitrary data with LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, .net-4.0, grouping

In C#, given a class definition like this:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public String A { get; set; }
    public String B { get; set; }
    public String C { get; set; }
}
```

and given a collection of `SomeObject`s, I want my application to be able to count the number of SomeObjects grouped by any combination of A, B and C.  Is there a LINQ query I can use to do this, or if not, some algorithm I can write?

Given this:

```
List<SomeObject> objects;
bool GroupByA;
bool GroupByB;
bool GroupByC;
```

I want to group `objects` by SomeObject.A if GroupByA is true, by B if GroupByB is true, and by C if GroupByC is true.  I understand that I can do any *one* of these by `objects.GroupBy(o => o.A);` but then how do I then go and group by B and/or C?

I hope that makes sense.  What I'm hoping to get out is something like this:

```
There are 10 objects with A = "Smith" and B = "London"
There are 20 objects with A = "Jones" and B = "London"
There are 44 objects with A = "Jones" and B = "Inverness"
```

etc. etc.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you do do a `loop` with a `.Where(o => o.A == "Smith" && o.B == "London");` And change the values every loop?

Comment: @Bazzz: I'd also have to know the range of possible values in advance, which i don't - if someone was added to objects that lived outside of London or Inverness, they wouldn't get counted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var groups = objects.GroupBy(o => new {
    A = GroupByA ? o.A : null,
    B = GroupByB ? o.B : null,
    C = GroupByC ? o.C : null
});

foreach (var g in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("There are {0} objects with A = {1} and B = {2} and C = {3}",
                 g.Count(),
                 g.Key.A,
                 g.Key.B,
                 g.Key.C);
}
```

Some more sophisticated formatting can be done to handle `C=null` key part.

Comment: I must say, for someone who's just starting out with LINQ, that's simply awesome.  I would never have thought it could be done with just one statement.

Comment: Matt, how do you know snowbear's just starting out with LINQ?? :-). sorry for the sillyness. but agreed, nice little solution

Comment: whoops - it is of course me that's just starting out with LINQ :-P

Comment: i know, jist pullin yer leg.. keep it up

Comment: @jim: I don't know why I didn't get it from the documentation.  I mean, according to MSDN, it's as simple as GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>, Func<TSource, TElement>, Func<TKey, IEnumerable<TElement>, TResult>, IEqualityComparer<TKey>).  Like, duh.

Comment: @Matt, I've used the simple one which is `GroupBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can group by an anonymous type with two properties:

```
objects.GroupBy(o => new { o.A, o.B });
```